# Delicacies of Emilia-Romagna region

Tags: food-and-drink, italy, reggio-emilia

I would like to know and ask about food of `Emilia-Romagna` region, to be more specific what should I try in Rimini?

I've off course googled about this, and I have some clues of Italian food, we all do, but I want something specific, what should we try?

What Italian's love to eat in this part of Italy?

I know it's a bit wide subject, but I was hoping that someone from Italy or anyone who often visit `Rimini` and this region, can point out what is specific regarding food in `Emilia-Romagna` delicacies.

Comment: You should probably try the "Piadina romagnola": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piadina 
Typical fillings are rocket and squacquerone cheese, ham and squacquerone cheese.

Comment: Nice, I read about this somewhere, but didn't think it was specific for this region, now that I now, I will certainly try it. One question, is `vino di casa` a good choice to try in this region, because lot's of sites suggesting it's a tradition to drink wine at dinner in Italy?

Comment: Hey, backticked (``) blocks are usually read a character at a time by screen readers and are only recommended for code and other instances where what's being written *isn't* words from any human language. Italics (using `*` around your text) often works great for words from a foreign language.

Comment: Usually *vino della casa* means wine from a local producer. Restaurants serve it on tap instead of bottled. It's usually "good enough" and "cheap enough" compared to bottled wine. Actual quality will vary from restaurant to restaurant, sites like tripadvisor.com may help in your decision.